# Having trouble with Javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, function

This code is for drawing a snake to make the snake game. I am having trouble understanding the parameters of the drawSnake function and calling the function

```
  //ctx is a reference to the id of the canvas
  var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
  var WIDTH = 500;
  var HEIGHT = 500;
  var snakeList;
  ctx.font = "20px Calibri";
  var snakeBody = {
    width:20,
    height:20,
    color:'green'
  };


  drawSnake = function(sb,i) {                                    
    ctx.save();
    if (i == 0)
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    else
      ctx.fillStyle = snakeBody.color;
    ctx.fillRect(sb.x,sb.y,snakeBody.width,snakeBody.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  startGame = function() {
    snakeList = [{x:220,y:200},
                 {x:210,y:200},
                 {x:200,y:200}];
    snakeList.forEach(drawSnake);
  }
  startGame();
```

in `drawSnake` function,

1. Where is `i` coming from and what is it?
2. How is `sb` somehow taking values from snake List when `snakeList` is not called in the `drawSnake` function

in `startGame` function, where `snakeList.forEach(drawSnake);`

1. How is drawSnake being called without passing in its parameters?

Comment: Analyze it in debugger.

Comment: look up `forEach`.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp.  `forEach` iterates through the array, and for each object in the array, passes that object and the array index value as the two parameters to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) assumes the argument to `forEach` is a function, which takes the parameter `callback`:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
    // your code
});
```

Because `drawSnake` is a function, when you do:

```
snakeList.forEach(drawSnake);
```

for each item in `snakeList`, the function `drawSnake` will be called with `sb` set to the current item, and `i` set to the index of that item.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is coming from the `drawSnake` function. Usually, people name `i` a variable to denote an index; that serves to indicate a value or quantity.

forEach will call drawSnake by iterating over the `snakeList` array and passing each x and y value to drawSnake.

From MDN documentation:

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

The first argument to forEach() is a callBack function (so in this case, `drawSnake`) and the second argument is the index of the current item (hence `i`)

Answer (score 0):

The key here comes down to what `Array.forEach` does.  Try this example.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.forEach(function (x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

`Array.forEach` takes a parameter, a function, and executes that function for every item in the array.  In this example, `console.log()` will be called 5 times, once for each item in the array.  In the console, you'll see every element, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, on its own line in the console.

In your code, we have an array of objects assigned to `snakeList`.  When you call `snakeList.forEach()`, it's going to execute whatever function is passed in for each element.  Rather than an anonymous function like in my example, your code is calling `drawSnake`.  It's effectively like doing the following:

```
drawSnake({x:220,y:200}, 0);
drawSnake({x:210,y:200}, 1);
// etc.
```

The second parameter passed to the function callback for forEach is the index of the item in the array.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach